# 3d transformation, inverse transformation not symmetrical

Tags: css

I have two containers, each contains a nested div structure that are having the 3d transformations applied to them. The effect is to simulate a piece of paper being unfolded down the centre line.

You see the current state of the code [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveawb/pXAhF/).

The problem that I have encountered is attempting to reverse the right had animation on the left.

I've achieved what I have already by placing each starting segment with `translate3d()`.

The HTML structure is as follows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="slice s1">
            <div class="slice s2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="slice s1">
            <div class="slice s2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.left` and `.right` elements are positioned absolutely within `.container` and set to `left:50%` to centre them. The first element of `.left` is then given a negative `left:-100px` to position it correctly.

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-200px;
    left:50%;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
    perspective: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}

.left {
    left: -100px;
}

.right {
    left:0;
}
```

The `transform3d()` then places each segment either 99px to the right or 99px to the left depending on their container.

If you see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveawb/pXAhF/) , you'll notice that the angles are off on the left hand portion. I am not sure how to fix this to make it all evened out and symmetrical.

The 3d planes are not right as demonstrated in this inspection in Chrome:

[image: Chrome Inspection]

Can anyone help guide me to making this symmetrical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 sides are symetrical, it's your point of view that isn't.

Try:

```
.right {
    left:0;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0px 150px;
    perspective-origin: 0px 150px;
}
```

And will solve it.

An even better approach would be to have the left and right sides have the size that you see (they are bigger on the right).

That would make the perspective point by default (center center) to be also symetrical, and wouldn't need to set it to an arbitrary value

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks @vals. Looking much better.